# UIButton title disappears when button disabled

Tags: ios, uibutton, title

I have a system `UIButton`, when I do this

```
self.abutton.enabled = NO;
```

The `button’s` title disappears, I do not want it to disappear I just want it to be non clickable. What should I do?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Do you have a background that's gray (which is the color of a disabled button's title) so it's just not showing?

Comment: No I haven’t, the button is added from the storyboard, I didn’t edit anything of its properties in code except for the target

Comment: Hmmm... that's strange. You can also try setting userInteractionEnabled to NO, instead of setting enabled to NO; you don't get any visual indication with that method.

Comment: than use self.abutton.userInteractionEnabled = NO; !!

Comment: self.aButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Worked fine, thank youu:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yourButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

OR

yourButton.enabled = NO;

[yourButton setTitle:@"ButtonDisabled" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

[Check this Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uicontrol_class/reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIControlState)

**List of States:**

```
UIControlStateNormal

UIControlStateHighlighted

UIControlStateDisabled

UIControlStateSelected

UIControlStateApplication

UIControlStateReserved
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you add title for disabled state of your button e.g -

```
[YOUR_BTN setTitle:@"xyz" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

If not than add it

Answer (score 1):

As per my understandings you can use following code. Hope this will help you.

```
   self.aButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```